# Google MAP ломается при ширине больше 800

Tags: php, javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть карта с метками, они работает когда ширина более 800. Когда больше метки остаются, но карта серый фон и все. Уже пробовали отключать файлы скриптов, и много другого. Опытным путем добился некоторого исключения и понял что мою карту блочит, вроде, какой-то другой скрипт. Отключение их ничего не дало, но другого варианта я не нашел.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Проблема в том, что не отображается карта (как видно из скрина). А в результате я хотел бы получить карту работающую, чтобы отображалась собственно сама карта....